# Z-Index not respected by IE8 when using <embed> tag to embed PDF

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, position, z-index

I embed a PDF onto a page like so, for viewing in < IE9.

```
<embed src="path/to/pdf" type="application/pdf" wmode="opaque" width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
</embed>
```

I have a menu that appears on mouse over at the top of the page that should appear *on top* of the embedded PDF, but it does not. See screenshot: 
[image]

I've tried adding different CSS position declarations to the  tag, its parents, and the menu that should appear on mouse hover.

To experiment with z-index and IE, I created this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LtSA8/4/show/

The yellow box should appear on top of the embedded PDF according to its z-index, but in IE8 it does not (it does in FF).

Can someone please help?

UPDATE: I've also tried adding the following to my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:doc|pdf)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition inline
  Header unset Accept-Ranges
  Header unset Cache-Control
  SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
</FilesMatch>
```